# Trying to rank rows based off a column and receiving Typerror: 'Nonetype' object is not callable in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a two dimensional data frame of about 18,000 stocks and their daily close prices for the last 11 years. So the table looks like this:

| date | tic | prccd | daily_return | 24M_TTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/04/05 | AIR | 41.99 | -0.002 | 0.795 |
| 2021/04/06 | AIR | 41.61 | -0.009 | 0.785 |
| 2010/01/06 | ADCT.1 | 6.61 | -0.841 | -0.058 |
| 2010/01/07 | ADCT.1 | 6.64 | -0.004 | -0.0007 |

I am trying to rank each row based on tic like so:

`returns['rank'] = returns.groupby('tic').rank()`

I receive Keyerror: 'Nonetype' object is not callable.

For context, I am trying to calculate the 24 month trailing volatility and need specific rows to be NaN for the math to work. I coded as follows:

```
returns['daily_return'] = returns['prccd'].pct_change()
returns['24M_TTM'] = returns['daily_return'].rolling(504).sum()
```

I'd like the output to look like so:

| date | tic | prccd | daily_return | 24M_TTM | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/04/05 | AIR | 41.99 | -0.002 | 0.795 | 2999 |
| 2021/04/06 | AIR | 41.61 | -0.009 | 0.785 | 3000 |
| 2010/01/06 | ADCT.1 | 6.61 | -0.841 | -0.058 | 1 |
| 2010/01/07 | ADCT.1 | 6.64 | -0.004 | -0.0007 | 2 |

Later I would make certain ranks of columns NaN

I've done some research and I believe it's because it is using pandas.series and not dataframe. I just can't seem to figure out how to get around that. Is there a way to rank by the 'tic' column where it counts successively and restarts at a new ticker and or use dataframe instead of series?

Comment: If you post expected output then it'll be easier for us

Comment: Also I think you have a typo where you're using `group` I think you meant `groupby`

Comment: Sorry Ill put an expected output when I have my PC

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['tic'])['datadate].rank()
```

I hope this helps someone besides myself.